# Handling Deep linking on old Android browsers

Tags: android, uri, deep-linking, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I am implementing Deep linking and App Indexing for the first time, its just a month ago it was launched for public use so lack of help online. I have read all available resources, but there are still some problems.

I am clear about things like, Deep linking should be implemented before App indexing, it should implemented **android-app//com.example.com** schema and many other.

So here the puzzle begins:

**Confusions with Deep linking**: Google is offering two URL patterns:

1. http://www.example.com/path/to/something
2. android-app://com.example.com/example/path/to/something

So almost in every example, I've found they have used both patterns. But for App Indexing only 2nd one is required.

But I know if I implement 1st one as well, it will open my app on normal web link as well. I don't know if this is good do or not?

Another problem with Deep linking, there are many browsers out there(Opera, UC) or Android OS which does't support 2nd format of URI, they simply trigger google search.

**So what is the way to make none deep link supported browser to handle this uri: `android-app://com.example.com/example/path/to/something`?**

**Note: I will be using this URI Format to open my app from website: android-app://com.example.com/example/path/to/something, so problem is to handle when this url format is not support.**

Comment: Here's an intent that launches the Zxing barcode scanner app. It follows the syntax thus:

intent:
   //scan/
   #Intent; 
      package=com.google.zxing.client.android; 
      scheme=zxing; 
   end; 
To launch the Zxing barcode scanner app, you encode your href on the anchor as follows:

  <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a> Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you can use custom schemes and/or HTTP schemes for your deep links. What you should not do is to duplicate the deep link destination between the different schemes.

You can find an article regarding App Indexing best practices here (https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html) and here (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/android-app-indexing-is-now-open-for.html).